# behaviour of try catch and finally with return statement workflow in c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch, finally

I have little doubt about this try, catch and finally with return statement workflow...

This function is used to retrieve employee leave information for supervisor view. It works very well, but if there data found for if statement it will be return otherwise else block will be return. Even if the both get returns, its going to finally statement.
I don't know why?

Code snippet here:

```
List<Leave> ILeaveData.GetLeaveForSupervisorView(int userID)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Storeprocedurename", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = userID;

    // Get employee leave information

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(ds);


        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Leave> leave = new List<Leave>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                leave.Add(CreateLeaveForAdminViewFromDataRow(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]));
            }
            return leave; // if data found then statement return here
        }
        else
        {
            return null; // otherwise return here
            // throw new Exception("Data Error");
         }
      }
      catch (SqlException err)
      {
          IErrorLog elog = new ErrorLog(_connectionString);
          elog.LogSystemError(err);
          throw new ApplicationException("Data Error", (Exception)err);
      }
      finally
      {
          if (con != null)
          {
              con.Close();
          }
       }
   }
```

regards
Sarva

Comment: `finally` always runs after a try block. Is there any reason you don't want it executed?

Comment: hi Ryan i agree with you... but The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method. thats why im asking why its not happen in above statement?

Comment: i hope you understand what i want...

Comment: See Darren's answer and the first paragraph of the MSDN site he linked to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally statements are always executed, even if no exception occurs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.110).aspx:

> Typically, the statements of a finally block run when control leaves a try statement. The transfer of control can occur as a result of normal execution, of execution of a **break, continue, goto, or return** statement, or of propagation of an exception out of the try statement.

Comment: The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method. thats why im asking why its not happen in above statement?

Comment: @Sarrrva It happens, because it **always** happens. If you don't want it to happen, you can create a `bool returned`, set it to true *before* calling `return` then check for `if (returned)` and exit the `finally` block with yet another `return`

Comment: Wow there is Good explanation darren... thanks a lot... my +5

Comment: Answer is By using a finally block, you can clean up any resources that are allocated in a try block, and you can run code even if an exception occurs in the try block. Typically, the statements of a finally block run when control leaves a try statement. The transfer of control can occur as a result of normal execution, of execution of a break, continue, goto, or return statement, or of propagation of an exception out of the try statement.

Answer (score 3):

`finally` block is designed to always execute, regardless of whether exception has been thrown or not.

Answer (score 1):

Final block will be executed in all cases.